# Converting text content in a variable to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string variable named `teststring` and it contains some content like

```
  teststring="<span>hi this is a test content</span>"
```

Is there any c# code to copy that contents in a pdf file?

Comment: This is not a real question for Stackoverflow. It is not clear at all. More important is, what have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Itextsharp](http://itextpdf.com/) Library to produce a PDF file from a HTML page.

*iText ® is a library that allows you to create and manipulate PDF documents. It enables developers looking to enhance web- and other applications with dynamic PDF document generation and/or manipulation.
Developers can use iText to:
Serve PDF to a browser,
Generate dynamic documents from XML files or databases,
Use PDF's many interactive features,
Add bookmarks, page numbers, watermarks, etc.
Split, concatenate, and manipulate PDF pages,
Automate filling out of PDF forms,
Add digital signatures to a PDF file,
iText is available in Java as well as in C#.*

Here is a simple tutorial to help you get started, [Export-HTML-DIV-contents-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-HTML-DIV-contents-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: how can i export an image for example a logo in the pdf file?

Comment: working with images is also very simple, just add the image to the document. You also have the flexibility to position the image at your desired location for a tutorial look at this link: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images